# Temp primary key is not back filled

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, strongly-typed-dataset

I'm using a typed data set in which I have a header table and child table.
I have defined as well a relation between the 2 tables.

When I create a new record in the Header table, it has a temporary primary key (-1) which is then automatically transferred in the FK_ID of the child table.
The problem is the real/final primary key generated by SQL Server is not backfilled in the table row. Therefore when the child row is inserted in SQL Server, the foreign key value is -1 and it generates an error.

Here below is my code:

```
    Dim dsAdminRate As New dsAdministrativeRates
    Dim daRateHeader As New dsAdministrativeRatesTableAdapters.ADMIN_RATES_HEADERTableAdapter
    Dim drRateHeader As dsAdministrativeRates.ADMIN_RATES_HEADERRow
    Dim daRateLine As New dsAdministrativeRatesTableAdapters.ADMIN_RATES_LINESTableAdapter
    Dim drRateLine As dsAdministrativeRates.ADMIN_RATES_LINESRow

    Try
        ' Create a new row.
        drRateHeader = dsAdminRate.ADMIN_RATES_HEADER.NewADMIN_RATES_HEADERRow
        With drRateHeader
            .RATE_NAME = txtRateName.Text
            .SOURCE_CCY_ID = ddlSourceCurrency.SelectedValue
            .DESTINATION_CCY_ID = ddlDestinationCurrency.SelectedValue
            .PERIODICITY_ID = ddlPeriodicity.SelectedValue
        End With
        ' Add the row to the ADMIN_RATES_HEADER table
        dsAdminRate.ADMIN_RATES_HEADER.Rows.Add(drRateHeader)



        ' Create a new exchange rate
        drRateLine = dsAdminRate.ADMIN_RATES_LINES.NewADMIN_RATES_LINESRow
        With drRateLine
            .SetParentRow(drRateHeader)
            .START_DATE = 20171213
            .END_DATE = 20171213
            .S_D_RATE = 1.2
            .D_S_RATE = 1 / 1.2
            .FK_ADMIN_RATES_HEADER = drRateHeader.ID
        End With
        ' Add the row to the ADMIN_RATES_LINES table
        dsAdminRate.ADMIN_RATES_LINES.Rows.Add(drRateLine)

        ' Save the header row to the database
        daRateHeader.Update(dsAdminRate.ADMIN_RATES_HEADER)

        ' Save the child row to the database
        daRateLine.Update(dsAdminRate.ADMIN_RATES_LINES)

    Catch ex As Exception
        ucMessage.Display("error", "An error occured: " & ex.Message)
    Finally
        dsAdminRate = Nothing
        daRateHeader = Nothing
        drRateHeader = Nothing
        daRateLine = Nothing
        drRateLine = Nothing
    End Try
```

Till so far I was not able to find an example or to understand why it behaves like this.

Thank in advance for your kind help

Comment: Have you unchecked 'Refresh the datatable' in the designer?

Comment: Thank you very much. I went to the dataAdapter config wizard and find the option which was unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a clear answer to this:

[image]

*image courtesy of flylib.com*

"Refresh the datatable" needs to be checked for db calculated values to be back-populated into the local datatable